# PNG img displays in Visual Studio Designer but not IE

Tags: internet-explorer, png, visual-studio-designer

I am currently writing a webpage. I want there to be a banner image on the top of the webpage. Here is my html and css:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Protect The Environment!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="http://intranet.kings.edu.hk/~s13977/banner.png"
            id="banner-image" 
            alt=""/>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

styles.css

```
body {
    background:#f8e4e4;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:medium;
}

#banner-image {
    height: 106px; 
    width: 582px;
}
```

As you can see, I *did* put the image in the html and the `src` is set to the correct url. You can copy the url and check. Here is how it looks from the Visual Studio Designer:
[image]

But when I run it with IE, it looks like this:
[image]

I tried to add this to the `#banner-image` css rule:

```
visibility:visible;
```

But it doesn't work at all. The page stays the same!

I think there is some problems with the `div` but I really want to keep it. It just makes things much easier to manage.

Comment: Have you tried running it in other browsers? If so, what's the result?

Comment: It might be that IE doesn't take kindly to the newline characters within the `img` tag.

Comment: If you want to be serious about developing web pages, you have to learn how to use developer tools in your browser. Once you do, you won't have to ask such questions (Or at least would ask much better questions)

Comment: @Boaz I deleted the new lines and it's still the same.

Comment: You stated we could check the image URL.  It is not working for me.

Comment: @trex005 Oops! maybe the server's down. Anyway, if it can't find the image, it should at least display a little cross!

Comment: @Sweeper Another shot in the dark - the URL suggests this is an image hosted on some internal university network. Are you sure it's actually accessible? It might be cached in Visual Studio, but not actually accessible when you're trying to run the page from home in a browser.

Comment: No, you provided an alt that is an empty string.  It should display that.  Try putting an alt in and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my testing, I didn't find any difference in HTML ordering, although I wasn't extremely thorough. Adding a float class directly to the image or in a surrounding `<div>` makes no difference, the images still do not show up.
Fortunately, the fix is quite simple! Just add three lines to your CSS. file and the problem is solved.

No hacks, no conditionals, just pure, validating CSS.

```
img
{
    position: relative;
}
```

For as many headaches I got from dealing with Internet Explorer's inadequacies, it was a slap on the face when I realized how simple the solution is. Relative **positioning is the magic fix in IE**, so try it out if you've got some odd quirk that's causing you grief!

**Note : Tested and workied fine**

Comment: Oh yes! I really liked IE before. But now? Not that much.

Comment: Yes it is the magic trick in IE, but what happens, if your position needs to be fixed? or cannot be relative due to requirements? this is a bandage on a gashing wound here.

Comment: @BarrJ thanks for extra tips. But `position: relative;` will not make any harm to view.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer doesn't recognize the newline character, because IE doesn't do automated encoding. Meaning that instead of:

```
"http://intranet.kings.edu.hk/~s13977/banner.png"
```

In your image path on IE you will get:

```
  "http://intranet.kings.edu.hk/%7Es13977/banner.png"
```

%7E is the url encoding of ~, Which will lead to a non-existent path of your image.

You need to use encodeUriComponent, or some other explicit encoding component for your link in order to get it work on IE.